# Complex, Compound, Complex-Compound, and ;?

Tags: syntactic-analysis

A compound sentence uses *for, and, nor, but, or, yet, so* to give the clauses equal weighting

> She didn't like to exercise, but she did at least eat healthy

A complex sentence makes one of the clauses subordinating, providing an emphasis on one of the caluses:

> While she didn't like to exercise, she did at least eat healthy.

Another option is sentences that uses a ;, but what is the a proper name for this sentence type, other than enhanced-compound (from what I've found)?

> She didn't like to exercise; she had gained weight despite her healthy
>   diet.

Answer (score 3):

You may want to read [Wikipedia's discussion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure) of how we classify sentences based on structure. For multi-clause sentences, what matters is whether they're dependent or independent and whether they're [coordinated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordination_(linguistics)) adequately, inadequately or not at all, not whether they're joined with a conjunction, punctuation or both (e.g. a conjunction plus a comma). However, fusion of independent clauses "inadequate" for coordination, with no conjunction and with no or inadequate punctuation, [gives a run-on sentence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentence_clause_structure#Run-on_sentences).